# How to create task from custom mediator in WSO2?

Tags: wso2, quartz-scheduler, wso2-esb

Is there any way to create scheduled task from WSO2 custom mediator? In my case, I want to create a task every time I called the custom mediator. And also I want the task to run in a specific time. Can I do this using the custom mediator? 
please help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Tasks are independent..when server starts up they start to execute in the configured pattern..

```
// I want to create a task every time I called the custom mediator//
```

What is the usecase here? I think , you can have task logic inside your custom mediator

Comment: Thanks for your response. In my case, I want to create a new task that do something everytime I called my custom mediator in proxy service. is this visible in WSO2?